# word fragments checker with a list and for loop analyzer

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

i'm trying to make a semi-word analyzer, here is my code:

```
score = 0
letter_combos = ["hel","goo","the"]
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence for anaysing!")
length = len(sentence)
for letter_combos in range (0, length):
    score += 1        
    print(score)
```

The idea is, if  i entered "hello there i'm good today" it should display the score as 3 but its just printing the length of the sentence. Any help on what I've done wrong and need to fix?

Comment: What's a "semi-word"? How is the score supposed to be calculated?

Comment: @mrkrieger1, what i mean by "semi-word" is fragments of a word, and the score should be calculated so in a sentence if there are three fragments then the score should be three.

Comment: You "semi-words" are called word fragments.

Comment: The reason it's returning the length of the string is because of your for loop. You're reassigning 'letter_combos' to be the counter in your for loop, counting between 0 and length-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most Pythonic way of solving your problem is to use list comprehension:

```
letter_combos = ["hel", "goo", "the"]
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence for analyzing: ")
score = sum(sentence.count(fragment) for fragment in letter_combos)
```

Comment: it works for what i want it to do, but the problem i face is if i enter hello three times it should say score = 3 but instead i get score = 1?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: it works perfectly!